# How to conditionally load different storyboards?

Tags: ios

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I decided to rely on [Parse](http://parse.com) for user signup and authentication flows of my app.

The problem is the following.

I want to load different scoreboards depending if the user logs in on signs up. For example if user signs up (or logs in first time) I want to take her through the tour. But next time user signs in she will see the main app view.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about parse but I can guid you for storyboard.

First of all you don't need two storyboard. One is enough to achieve this.

Design your tory board something like this:

```
UINavigationController(1)->UIViewController(signup)->UIViewController(Tour)->UINavigationController(2)->UIViewController(signin)
```

Make UINavigationController(1) your root view controller so when application load first time it will show UIViewController(signup).

Now in appDelegate white something like following in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method

```
if(ISSignUP)
{
    window.rootViewController = [window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UINavigationController(2)_ID"];
}
```

Here UINavigationController(2)_ID is identifier you give to UINavigationController(2)

Post comment if you want more guid or face any problem.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks! But with Parse I need to specify delegates for login and signup views in viewDidAprear method, as in this tutorial:
https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

I'm not sure what should I set these delegates to.